# cocoa close NSWindow

Tags: xcode, cocoa, nswindow

I'm trying to make a NSWindow close when I click a button for a new NSWindow. I'm not trying to connect the button to make it close because the button is what makes it open. Or can it do both? (i am very new to xcode, please excuse me if this sounds dumb)
Anyway here's my code I tried (no errors popped up or warning):

```
-(IBAction)switchTo:view2{
    [view1 performClose:(id)view1]; 
}
```

I have 3 iboutlets ,

```
IBOutlet NSWindow *view1;
IBOutlet NSWindow *view2;
IBOutlet NSWindow *view3;
```

I have a button in view1 that opens view2, and a button in view2 that opens view3.

My only problem is when I click the button in view1 to view2, I want view1 to close.

Comment: This question is very vague. I realize that you're new here; you'll get more and better answers if you edit your question to increase clarity. Tell us: what you have; what you're trying to do; what error you're seeing (if any) or how your code fails to meet your objective; what you think you don't understand. You can edit your question by hitting the 'edit' link below the tags.

Comment: thanks, i will try and explan better in a bew question posting..

Answer (score 0):

Use `[view1 orderOut:nil];` instead of performClose.

You can also connect a button with two selectors. Both will be called.

Comment: thanks for responding i really apreciate it... but something is still wrong, although once again no warnings or errors pop up, the window still will not close, is my IBaction wrong? i notice the siwtchTo has no color to it, does that mean its not valid or something? 


-(IBAction)switchTo:view2{
 
 [view1 orderOut:nil];
 
}

Comment: the method shouldn't have a : in this sense. call the method -(IBAction)switchToView2 {[view1 orderOut:nil];}